# .C# dataset.haschanges not working for the second row of table

Tags: c#-4.0

Addresses table has two rows. If first row is modified, HasChanges function is working as expected. 
 If second row is modified, HasChanges function is not working as expected.
 Please let me know how to rectify this. Thanks in advance.

```
     DataTable dt = dsDetails.Tables["Addresses"];
     this.BindingContext[dt].EndCurrentEdit();

     if (! dsDetails.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified))
          return false;
```

I tried with HasChanges() also.. but not worked.

Comment: AcceptChanges has been called? if called it will not work after that

Comment: where should we call AcceptChanges ?

Comment: After you modify the row, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx